# Fields finitely generated as $\mathbb Z$-algebras are finite?

Tags: commutative-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose $k$ is a field that is finitely generated as a ${\mathbb Z}$-algebra.  (That is, $k$ is a quotient of ${\mathbb Z}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ for some $n$). Does it follow that $k$ is finite?

Comment: A quick glance at [another post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56916/what-do-prime-ideals-in-kx-y-look-like) makes me think you should be able to first show that $K$ is of prime characteristic. Perhaps once that's established, you can determine the degree of $K$ over its prime subfield is finite?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes!
Consider the morphism 
$f:\mathbb Z\to k$ and the ideal $\mathfrak m=f^{-1}(0)\subset \mathbb Z$.
Since $\mathbb Z$ is a Jacobson ring and $(0)\subset k$ is maximal,   $\mathfrak m$ is maximal too and we obtain a morphism $\bar f:\mathbb F_p\to k$.
Since $k$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb F_p$ and is a field, it is actually a finite extension ("Zariski's version of the Nullstellensatz") and thus  $k$ is (set-theoretically!) finite.

*Edit*
Considering the  comments below , I had better state explicitly the theorem I have used.
**Theorem**
 Let $f:A\to B$ be a finitely generated $A$-algebra.
If $A$ is a Jacobson ring, , then $B$ is also Jacobson and for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m\subset B$ the ideal $f^{-1}(\mathfrak m)\subset A$ is also maximal.

*New Edit*
Here is a proof in the style of algebraic geometry, due to Akaki Tikaradze.
If $k$ has characteristic $p$ we conclude as above, using  Zariski.
If $\operatorname{char}k=0$, the morphism $f:\mathbb Z\to k \:$ is injective, so $A$ has no $\mathbb Z$-torsion and is thus $\mathbb Z$-flat.
But then $\operatorname{Spec}(k)\to\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ is open (flat+finite presentation $\implies$ open), i.e. $(0)\in\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ is open. Contradiction.
(This proof is absurdly sophisticated but it will probably appeal to scheme-theory addicts. 
Take it as some kind of joke...)

Comment: Georges:  My apologies....I thought this made perfect sense this morning but now I suddenly don't see it anymore.  ${\mathbb Q}$ is also a Jacobson ring, but the inverse image of (0) under the map ${\mathbb Z}\rightarrow {\mathbb Q}$ is not a maximal ideal.  What additional property are you using?

Comment: Dear Will, I'm using that $k$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb Z$ (and that $\mathbb Z $ is Jacobson).This is crucial as your counterexample correctly shows. An online reference is De Jong and collaborators' *Stack Project*, [Chapter 7: *Commutative Algebra*, Proposition 32.18 ](http://www.math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/algebra.pdf)

Comment: Another reference is the generalization of the nullstellensatz stated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullstellensatz .

Comment: Georges:  Yes, as I said, I understood this the first time, but somehow when I reread it late at night I lost track of the main point.  I remember why it made sense now!  Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: PS:  You wrote "Since "k" is a Jacobson ring" but  I think you meant "Since ${\mathbb Z}$ is a Jacobson ring"; I think you need this to apply the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Dear Will, I have written an edit which, I hope, will definitively clarify these matters.

Answer (score 14):

In case you are interested, here is a proof which also uses Zariski's lemma but no difficult theorems about Jacobson rings.

Write $R$ for the image of the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to k$, so that $k$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra and hence a finite extension of the fraction field of $R$ by Zariski's lemma. Thus it suffices to show that $R = \mathbb{F}_p$, which is to say $k$ has positive characteristic. If $R = \mathbb{Z}$, meaning $k$ has characteristic zero, then $k$ is a number field which is a finitely generated ring. But this is impossible: if we write $k = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r]$, then one can choose $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that all the denominators of coefficients in the minimal polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r$ divide $n$. This implies that $k$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$ must be a field, which is absurd.

Answer (score 3):

This is a mild generalization of Justin Campbell's answer, and the proof is almost the same as that of Proposition 7.8 in Atiyah and MacDonald's **Introduction to Commutative Algebra**. (This proposition is sometimes called the Artin-Tate Lemma.) The notation has been designed to make the analogy as clear as possible.

> Let $A\subset B\subset C$ be a tower of domains such that $B$ is the field of fractions of $A$, and $C$ is a field which is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra. Then (a) $C$ is a finite extension of $B$, and (b) $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra.

As (a) results immediately from Zariski's Lemma, it suffices to prove (b). The following statement is ironically stronger and easier to prove than (b):

> Assume that $C=A[x_1,\dots,x_m]$; that $y_1,\dots,y_n$ is a $B$-basis of $C$ with $y_1=1$; and that we have $$x_i=\sum_jb_{ij}y_j,\quad y_iy_j=\sum_kb_{ijk}y_k$$ with $b_{ij}$, $b_{ijk}$ in $B$. Then the $A$-algebra $B$ is generated by the $b_{ij}$ and the $b_{ijk}$.

The proof is straightforward, and left to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

When I read the proofs suggested in the answers half a year ago, I had the problem that I did not understand them because of a lack of algebra-knowledge. That's why I would like to share a (quite detailed) proof of the theorem which I finally understood:

I will use **Zariski's Lemma**: Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $A$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{K}$-algebra. If $A$ is a field, then it is a finite degree extension of $\mathbb{K}$.

Now the **proof**: There exist elements $a_1,...,a_n$ such that $R \cong \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n]$. In order to simplify our notation we may assume that $R = \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n]$. Why? - If $\phi \colon R \to \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n]$ is the isomorphism (that means $\phi(\frak{m}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n]$ is a maximal ideal) and $\pi \colon \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n] \to \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n]/(\phi(\frak{m}))$ denotes the canonical projection, then $\pi \circ \phi \colon R \to \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n]/(\phi(\frak{m}))$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with $\ker(\pi \circ \phi) = \frak{m}$. Hence the fundamental homomorphism theorem tells us that $R/\frak{m} \cong \mathbb{Z} [a_1,...,a_n]/(\phi(\frak{m}))$. So the ring of the left side is a finite field iff the ring on the right side is a finite field.

Let $i$ be the only possible ring homomorphism $i \colon \mathbb{Z} \to R/ \frak{m}$ and let $S := i( \mathbb{Z}) = \{z + m \mid z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Note that "$S$" is a ring. Since $\mathbb{Z}[a_1,...,a_n] = \{ f(a_1,...,a_n) \mid f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n] \}$, it is easy to see that $R/\frak{m} = \mathbb{Z}[a_1,...,a_n] / \frak{m} =$ $S[\bar a_1, ..., \bar a_n]$, where $\bar a_i = a_i + \frak{m}$, is a finitely generated $S$-algebra, hence a finite degree extension of the quotient field of $S$ (according to Zariski's lemma). 
Let's assume that $i$ is injective $\Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{Z} = S$. 
Thus $R/ \frak{m}$ is a finite degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. From this we conclude that the elements $\bar a_1,..., \bar a_n$ with $R/ \mathfrak{m} = \mathbb{Z}[\bar a_1,..., \bar a_n]$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ which means that they are zeros of certain monic polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. Now let $k$ be the product of the denominators of the coefficients of the minimal polynomials of the $\bar a_i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. As a consequence, the coefficients of the minimal polynomials can be considered as elements of $\mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}]$, hence the $\bar a_i$ are integral over $\mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}]$ and so the whole $R/ \mathfrak{m}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}]$.

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}], a \neq 0$ arbitrary, thus $a \in \mathbb{Q} \subseteq R/ \frak{m}$. Since $R/ \frak{m}$ is (a field and) integral over $\mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}]$, there exist $m \in \mathbb{N}, c_0,...,c_{m-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}]$ such that 
$$a^{-m} + c_{m-1} a^{-(m-1)}+\cdots+c_0 = 0,$$ and thus
$$a^{-1}=-(c_{n-1}+\cdots+c_0 a^{m-1}) \in \mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}].$$
Hence $\mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}]$ is a field, but that's a contradiction, since any prime number $q$, which does not divide $k$, cannot be invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[ \frac{1}{k}]$, because there is no element like $\frac{1}{q}$. So $i$ cannot be injective.

Thus there exists a $p \in \mathbb{N}$ prime such that $S = \mathbb{Z}/ p \mathbb{Z}$, hence $S$ is a finite field. From above we conclude that $R/ \frak{m}$ is a finite degree extension of a finite field, thus a finite field. $\Box$