# If A is a finitely generated algebra over the integers and m is a maximal ideal, then A/m is finite

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following:

Suppose $A=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ where $I$ is some ideal. Then for all $m \in Specm(A)$ we have $\mid A/m \mid$ is finite.

I've seen some proofs of this on the site, but I have the following restriction when proving this. I only know that "If A is a field and is contained in an affine K-domain, then A is algebraic," where K is a field. Are there any proofs of this that do not refer to theorems about Jacobson rings?

Comment: So Zariski lemma is "If K is a finitely generated algebra over a field k and if K is a field, then K is a finite field extension of k." I've proven that "If K is an algebra over field k, K is a field, and K is contained in a finitely generated k-domain, then K is algebraic over k". If K is contained in a finitely generated k-domain, then K must also be finitely generated, right? So I have "If K is a finitely generated algebra over a field k and if K is a field, then K is algebraic over k." But if K is algebraic over k, and finitely generated, then K is a finite field extension of k.

Comment: That is, $K=k[a_1,\ldots,a_r]=k(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ and thus $K:k$ is finite. This gives us Zariski's lemma. Does this look right? If so, how would I go about proving my initial theorem given Zariski lemma?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/148782/3217