# Property of prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_n]$. How to show that there exist a prime number $p$ such that $(p)+P$ is **not**  $\Bbb{Z}[X_1,...,X_n]$.

Comment: First note that it's enough to prove the claim for maximal ideals. Then use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148745/fields-finitely-generated-as-algebras-over-mathbb-z).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By considering $A := \mathbb{Z}[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]/P$, the question is equivalent to: Let $A$ be an integral domain (actually $A \neq 0$ suffices!) which is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra. We want to prove that there is a prime number $p$ such that $A/(p) \neq 0$.

Choose any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$. Then $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field which is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra. It is a well-known fact ([MO/30599](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30599/finitely-generated-algebra-over-z)) that this implies that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite field, say of characteristic $p$. Then $p \in \mathfrak{m}$ and therefore $A/\mathfrak{m}$ surjects onto $A/(p)$, and we are done.