# Prove that $\mathbb{C}$ is a finite $\mathbb{R}$-algebra and that $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ are not finite $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The third statement to prove would be "Prove that $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ are not finite $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras"

I thought about proving those statements in the following way:

**$\mathbb{C}$ is a finite $\mathbb{R}$-algebra**

The homomorphism we use is h : $\mathbb{R}$ -> $\mathbb{R}$ and h = $id_{\mathbb{R}}$, and once we have h($\mathbb{R}$) (which is $\mathbb{R}$ itself...) we can say that $\mathbb{C}$ = h($\mathbb{R}$)[i] (because we only have to add the element i to our set h($\mathbb{R}$) and the smallest ring containing h($\mathbb{R}$) and i is $\mathbb{C}$)

**$\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ are not finite $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras**

Because $\mathbb{Q}$ ⊂ $\mathbb{R}$ ⊂ $\mathbb{C}$ we only do it for $\mathbb{Q}$

There does not exist a one argument homomorphism which gives you any rational number you want, we can only work with some kind of homomorphism which gives you an integer. So to make $\mathbb{Q}$ out of it, we'd have to add an infinite amount of elements/numbers (all the "fully" rational ones like $\frac{1}{2}$, ...) to our set h($\mathbb{Z}$) to get $\mathbb{Q}$, but that's not what we're looking for. thus it's not a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-Algebra

**$\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ are not finite $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras**

Because $\mathbb{R}$ ⊂ $\mathbb{C}$ we only do it for $\mathbb{R}$

Same understanding as above, there does not exist a one argument homomorphism which gives you any irrational number you'd like (and there's an infinite amount of them), and working with a homomorphism which gives you a rational number as a result, the only way to create $\mathbb{R}$ out of h($\mathbb{Q}$) is to add all the irrational numbers to the set h($\mathbb{Q}$), but that's not what we're looking for

---

Is this enough? Because I kind of feel that it's too little, and that some sort of mathematical explanation is lacking (some equations for example)

Comment: One of the biggest problems with what you're doing is that it seems like you're assuming that subalgebras of finitely generated algebras are also finitely generated. [That is not true.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48798/non-finitely-generated-subalgebra-of-a-finitely-generated-algebra).  I'm not aware of a special exception for $\mathbb Z$, and I'm not saying there isn't a valid argument along these lines, but one should say something more to justify the lines that say "we can just do it for <the thing at the bottom>"

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{Q}$ ⊂ $\mathbb{R}$ ⊂ $\mathbb{C}$ we only do it for $\mathbb{Z}$? Sry it should be $\mathbb{Q}$ ⊂ $\mathbb{R}$ ⊂ $\mathbb{C}$ we only do it for $\mathbb{Q}$. But in the end, we could also do the same reasoning for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, that you can't create a homomorphism starting from $\mathbb{Z}$  and expand its image by a finite amount of elements to get $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. I mean it's kind of trivial and what I'm asking is if I need something more mathematically to show it

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148745/fields-finitely-generated-as-mathbb-z-algebras-are-finite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ are not finite $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras**

*Hint* for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$:
A finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra $A$ is the image of a ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n] \to A$ and therefore is countable.

*Hint* for $\mathbb Q$:
The numbers in $\mathbb Z[q_1,\dots,q_n]$ have denominators whose prime divisors come from a finite set.

Comment: 1. So because it is countable but R and C are uncountable, we cannot extent the image with a finite set of elements to get R and C?

Comment: 2. What are prime divisors? I don't really see how we should get the solution here

Comment: @user: 1: because the image is countable it cannot be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$; 2. The prime divisors of the denominators of the $q_i$ form a finite set.

Comment: "The prime divisors of the denominators of the  form a finite set." so how can I use this to show that Q is not a Z-algebra? I don't see the link here