# Why can't the $\text{Im}(\varphi)\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}$ be a ring homomorphism. Then $\ker{\varphi}\subset \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ is prime.

I'm assuming $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ a ring?

The argument I have is that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\ker{\varphi}$ is an integral domain. I'm looking back at my notes and I see I've written that for $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)\subset \mathbb{C}$, we can't say the image is a field because $\mathbb{C}$ is not a finite field. I'm confused because I thought any 'structured' subset of $\mathbb{C}$ could be a subfield.

Comment: What do you mean by "'structured' subset"?  Is the ring $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb C$ structured? To say the obvious, it's not a field, of course.

Comment: To elaborate on peter a g's comment, it is not true that a subring of a field is necessarily a field, and the image of a ring homomorphism is a subring of the codomain

Comment: For the conclusion that $\ker \varphi$ is prime you don't need the fact that $\text{im}  \varphi$ is not a field. You just need that $\text{im} \varphi$ is an integral domain, which it is, because it is a subring of a field. If you want to argue that $\ker \varphi$ is not maximal, then of course you need that $\text{im}  \varphi$ is not a field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that if the image is a field, then it either contains a finite field or $\mathbb Q$. If it contains a finite field then it can't be a subfield of $\mathbb C$ because they have different characteristics, so that's one possibility ruled out. If it contains $\mathbb Q$, then you also get a contradiction, because no field containing $\mathbb Q$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, but $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\operatorname{ker}\varphi$ (which is isomorphic to $\operatorname{im}\varphi$ by one of the isomorphism theorems) is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra by definition.

A reference for the last fact is [Fields finitely generated as $\mathbb Z$-algebras are finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148745/fields-finitely-generated-as-mathbb-z-algebras-are-finite)