# Calculating quotient ring over polynomial ring without guessing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose we have a quotient ring over a polynomial ring, i.e. we have an ideal $I$ and a ring, $K[X_1,...,X_n]$, then when we can we identify $K[X_1,...,X_n]/I$?

What do I mean by this? Well, for example, we have $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x]$.

So given an ideal, and a ring, is there any way of seeing what $K[X_1,...,X_n)/I$ is "naturally" isomorphic to, in a sense?

I've come across this when trying to identify prime ideals. I.e., given an ideal, how can we quickly check that it's prime?

Comment: Checking an ideal is prime is a very hard task in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first question you are asking for a classification of quotients of the polynomial ring, right?

This is (nearly) impossible. Let me give a few reasons why.

If we relax the conditions of polynomial ring a bit, i.e. we allow polynomial rings over $\mathbb{Z}$ with infinite variables, then any ring is of this form. Classifying all rings is a too hard problem.

But even if you only allow $K$ to be a field and finitely many variables, this task seems impossible. The basic objects of study in [algebraic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255063/why-study-algebraic-geometry/257528#257528) are  varieties. If you restrict to affine varieties over a field $K$ they are up to an equivalence of categories the same as finitely generated $K$-algebras, which are quotients of a polynomial ring over $K$. There are partial results, but there are no complete classification results.

What we do know is that if we take the quotient of a ring by a prime ideal (resp. maximal ideal), then we get a domain (resp. field).

In one variable you can use the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).    For two variables the prime ideals are "known" see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56921).

There is no general criterion to check if an ideal is prime. In one variable this is the same as finding irreducible polynomials. There are partial results as  [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) and [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) among others, but even in one variable there is no easy way.