# Concerning the evaluation map

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $r=r(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and define $e_{\alpha,\beta} : \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}$ by $e_{\alpha,\beta}(r(x,y)):=r(\alpha,\beta)$.

If I am not wrong, $e_{\alpha,\beta}$, the evaluation map, is a ring homomorphism (it is known to be a ring homomorphism for one variable; I guess that it is still a ring homomorphism for more than one variable?).

The kernel of $e_{\alpha,\beta}$ is the maximal ideal $(x-\alpha,y-\beta)$.

Now let $p=p(x,y),q=q(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with $n=\deg(f) \geq  2$ and  $m=\deg(g) \geq 2$.

> Can we find a commutative ring $R$ and a ring homomorphism $e: \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to R$
>   such that $(p,q)$ is the kernel of $e$?

(The special case where $R$ is an integral domain and $e$ is an epimorphism, in other words, $(p,q)$ is a prime ideal, was dealt with [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56916/what-do-prime-ideals-in-kx-y-look-like/2280554#2280554)).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Surely you are familiar with quotient rings?

Comment: Thanks. Please, could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what quotient rings are for.  Very generally, if $A$ is any ring and $I$ is any (two-sided) ideal in $A$, then the quotient map $A\to A/I$ is a ring homomorphism whose kernel is $I$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is ok if we require that $R$ is just an arbitrary commutative ring.