# An ideal $\langle x,y \rangle$ in $k[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Please help. Is an ideal $\langle x,y \rangle$ in $k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field, a prime ideal? I can't prove it. Probably it should be shown that $k[x,y]/\langle x,y \rangle$ is an integral domain, but I don't know what it is isomorphic with.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56916/what-do-prime-ideals-in-kx-y-look-like

Comment: hint: consider the map $k[x,y]\to k$ defined by $p(x,y)\mapsto p(0,0)$. what are the kernel and the image of this map?

Comment: Alternatively, it's easy to show that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is a maximal ideal (and therefore prime).