# For any $n\in \mathbb Z$ can we classify closed subsets of affine $n$ space? For algebraicly closed field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraicly closed field.

and let $\mathbb A^n(k)$ be our affine n space:

For $n=1$ we can clasify our closed zariski subsets of 1-space:

These are finite point sets and whole space and empty set.

For $n\ge 2$ what is the good approach to understand general closed subsets? I am revising my commutative algebra course and a bit confused and want to see these closed subsets with intuitive and good explanatory way.

Comment: The closed subsets are of the form $V(I)$ for an ideal $I$ of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Otherwise I don't know of a nice description that works for $n\geq 2$ in general. The $n=1$ case is very simple since, other than the zero ideal, the only prime ideals of $k[x]$ are maximal.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56916/what-do-prime-ideals-in-kx-y-look-like for $n=2$.